# Is the Smyril Line ferry from Denmark to Iceland an enjoyable experience?

Tags: ferries, iceland, denmark

A Smyril Line passenger & car ferry called the Norröna sails from Hirtshals in northern Denmark via Torshavn in the Faeroe Islands to Seydisfjördur in Iceland, roughly once a week all year round.

Whilst flights are cheaper, I am tempted to take the ferry for a more interesting experience however, particularly in Europe, some ferries are functional and often not very pleasant (Bay of Biscay for example).

What kind of experience is the Smyril Line and is it any way superior (sustainability / cultural / enjoyability) to a flight to Iceland?

Comment: Not an answer, because I do not have first hand experience, but looking at their web site pictures it looks pretty awesome sauce to me. You can also Google search for ms narrona and choose images and look at what others have posted... pretty posh for a ferry, imo.

Comment: It does doesn't it?   :-) I just want to check I am not going to be battered like a penny in a spin dryer haha.

Comment: Well, it IS the North Sea and a storm would not be ... fun?

Comment: Be mindful of the weather. The North Sea is no joke. We were in Iceland about a month ago and despite it being the middle of the summer it was cold & rainy and sometimes zero visibility,

Answer (score 3):

Got to this roundabout because stackexchange celebrates its oldest sites.  We took the Norroena to and from the Faroer for the 2015 total solar eclipse.  The captain didn't want to take it out of the harbor for cloud dodging so we ended up clouded out while clear views were close by.  But the ship is great and quite stable and the food was excellent and driving around the Faroer is very worthwile.

Comment: Thanks Rob - that is useful